# Customizing login pages

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I want to have a custom login page for the IS.  I'm following the documentation here:
https://docs.wso2.org/display/IS460/Customizing+Login+Pages

However, I don't know exactly what is meant by step 3: "redirecting or forwarding from 'authenticationendpoint' to your webapp".  How do I do this?  Is it by changing a configuration within the IS installation?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a configuration change. Under the WSO2IS multiple java web applications are deployed here: /repository/deployment/server/webapps . Under the authenticationendpoint webapp you can modify, theme the pure HTML pages with CSS.